# How to match this pattern ? (Java/regex)

Tags: java, regex

I need to transform the string:

```
"%s blabla %s"
```

into:

```
"%1$s blabla %2$s"
```

My code is as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("%s");
Matcher tokenMatcher = pattern.matcher(value);
int index = 1;
while(tokenMatcher.find()){
    String replacement = "%"+String.valueOf(index++)+"\\$s";        
    value = tokenMatcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

The problem is that the program gets in an infinite loop and I don't understand why. Somehow `%1$s` is matched by `%s`

```
%1$s blabla %s
%2$s blabla %s
%3$s blabla %s
%4$s blabla %s
%5$s blabla %s
%6$s blabla %s
%7$s blabla %s
%8$s blabla %s
%9$s blabla %s
%10$s blabla %s
etc...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset your matcher with the new value:

```
while (tokenMatcher.find()) {
  String replacement = "%" + String.valueOf(index++) + "\\$s";
  value = tokenMatcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
  tokenMatcher.reset(value); // reset
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

The reason is that replaceFirst() reset the matcher to the beginning but does not change the string it is currently matching, it's still contains the old string. You have to do that yourself to update the matcher.

Answer (score 2):

try resetting the `tokenMatcher` in the loop.

```
while(tokenMatcher.find()){
    String replacement = "%"+String.valueOf(index++)+"\\$s";        
    value = tokenMatcher.replaceFirst(replacement);
    tokenMatcher = pattern.matcher(value);
}

System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(matcher.find()){
    matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, "%" + String.valueOf(index++) + "\\$s");
}
matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
```

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#8

Comment: It would be good to add a line with `StringBuffer` initialization as OP did not have it in his initial code; but it's nice solution too (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 1;

        for (String s : input.split("%s")) {
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s %d", s, "%"+i+++"$"));


       }

String newString = stringBuilder.toString();
```